# How to Retrieve data from oracle database using Ajax Jquery with spring Mvc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, spring-batch

I am working with spring batch , I have configured my job to be executed by clicking on a button (spring MVC).
all information about my job are in `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION` in the database.

I want to have this scenario:

-when I load the page , the table contains all the records existing in the database

-when I click on the button to execute my job, the last  record added in the database is added in the front end of my table.

This is what I have done But still not working!

Here is the content of BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION.java file :

```
public class BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION {

private int JOB_EXECUTION_ID ;
private int VERSION;
private int JOB_INSTANCE_ID;
private Time CREATE_TIME ;
private Time START_TIME;
private Time END_TIME;
private String STATUS;
private String EXIT_CODE;
private String EXIT_MESSAGE;
private Time LAST_UPDATED;
public BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION(){

}
public int getJOB_EXECUTION_ID() {
    return JOB_EXECUTION_ID;
}
public void setJOB_EXECUTION_ID(int jOB_EXECUTION_ID) {
    JOB_EXECUTION_ID = jOB_EXECUTION_ID;
}
public int getVERSION() {
    return VERSION;
}
public void setVERSION(int vERSION) {
    VERSION = vERSION;
}
public int getJOB_INSTANCE_ID() {
    return JOB_INSTANCE_ID;
}
public void setJOB_INSTANCE_ID(int jOB_INSTANCE_ID) {
    JOB_INSTANCE_ID = jOB_INSTANCE_ID;
}
public Time getCREATE_TIME() {
    return CREATE_TIME;
}
public void setCREATE_TIME(Time cREATE_TIME) {
    CREATE_TIME = cREATE_TIME;
}
public Time getSTART_TIME() {
    return START_TIME;
}
public void setSTART_TIME(Time sTART_TIME) {
    START_TIME = sTART_TIME;
}
public Time getEND_TIME() {
    return END_TIME;
}
public void setEND_TIME(Time eND_TIME) {
    END_TIME = eND_TIME;
}
public String getSTATUS() {
    return STATUS;
}
public void setSTATUS(String sTATUS) {
    STATUS = sTATUS;
}
public String getEXIT_CODE() {
    return EXIT_CODE;
}
public void setEXIT_CODE(String eXIT_CODE) {
    EXIT_CODE = eXIT_CODE;
}
public String getEXIT_MESSAGE() {
    return EXIT_MESSAGE;
}
public void setEXIT_MESSAGE(String eXIT_MESSAGE) {
    EXIT_MESSAGE = eXIT_MESSAGE;
}
public Time getLAST_UPDATED() {
    return LAST_UPDATED;
}
public void setLAST_UPDATED(Time lAST_UPDATED) {
    LAST_UPDATED = lAST_UPDATED;
}
}
```

and here is my view :

```
 <div>
        <table id="contactTableResponse" class="table tr">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>JOB_INSTANCE_ID</th>
                    <th>START_TIME</th>
                    <th>END_TIME</th>
                    <th>EXIT_CODE</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Spring-Ajax</th>
                    <td colspan="4">JQuery Ajax</td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>
                <c:forEach items="${jobs}" var="BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION">
                        <tr>

                        <td>${BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION.JOB_INSTANCE_ID}</td>
                        <td>${BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION.START_TIME}</td>
                        <td>${BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION.END_TIME}</td>
                        <td>${BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION.EXIT_CODE}</td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

The ajax call:

```
    $('#JobBtn').click( function() {
  $('#JobBtn').click( function() {
    alert('in submit function');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'load',

        success : function(response) {  
            alert(response);   
           },  
           error : function(e) {  
            alert('Error: ' + e);   
           }  
    });
});
```

*Updated*

this is my controller:

```
 public class AjacController {

@Inject
@Named(value = "dataSource")
 private DataSource dataSource1;

 @RequestMapping(value="/load" )
 public ModelAndView connect(){


    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("");
    BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION batch=null;
     List<BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION> list =null;
ResultSet resultSet = null;
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
Connection connection = null;
String select= "select JOB_INSTANCE_ID, START_TIME,END_TIME,EXIT_CODE  from BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION";

 try {
    connection = dataSource1.getConnection();
    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(select);
    resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    while(resultSet.next()){


   batch.setJOB_EXECUTION_ID(resultSet.getInt("JOB_INSTANCE_ID")) ;
   batch.setSTART_TIME(resultSet.getTime("START_TIME")) ;
   batch.setEND_TIME(resultSet.getTime("END_TIME")) ;
   batch.setEXIT_CODE(resultSet.getString("EXIT_CODE")) ;
   list.add(batch);
   model.addObject("listJobs", list);


    }
  return model ;
```

}

but data is not displayed in my table!
 Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You have to use JDBC to connect to any database from Java (or) you can even use an ORM framework like Hibernate. You can find lot of articles on both of them in internet. Considering your use case is simple, I suggest you go with simple JDBC

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Arkantos , Yes I've made a simple jdbc connection to database , but how to integrate the `connection.java` in my ajax call ?

Comment: Simplest way is to create a servlet, map it to some url and use that url in your Ajax. If you want to use spring mvc, create a controller class with a method in it, add respective request mappings, in that method use your JDBC code

Comment: Thanks @arkantos,  I created a controller that implements a method  which get data from database , but still not working ! Please see my update ..

Comment: Cool.. As you're making GET request from browser, update your request mapping to handle that type of request by using method attribute like this `@RequestMapping(value="/load" method="GET")`

Comment: Not working :/ 

Is my ajax call correct?

Comment: Nope your URL should be `/ur-context-root/load`